# How to completely remove Netbeans

Tags: uninstall, software-uninstall, purge

I cannot remove Netbeans from my system. When I locate `uninstall.sh` file, located in `/usr/local/netbeans-12.4/`, it cannot be executed. When I `cd` into that directory and run `./uninstall.sh`, I get:

```
Configuring the installer...
Searching for JVM on the system...
Extracting installation data...
Running the installer wizard...

Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "main"
```

Any idea how to completely remove everything related to this software from my system (20.04 Focal Fossa)? Thank you.

Comment: I have added location of `uninstall.sh`. I have run it this way: `./uninstall.sh`.  I do not know how did I install Netbeans, it was a while ago.

Comment: I have added complete result of the script.

Comment: If you have installed in `/usr/local`, you would have done it as root. I doubt this will make much difference but what happens if you try `sudo /usr/local/netbeans-12.4/uninstall.sh`?

Comment: Sudo gave me more information that led to solution. `Can't load library: /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/lib/libawt_xawt.so` - when I installed requested JDK, uninstaller executed.

Answer (score 1):

Running the command as admin (`sudo ./uninstall.sh`) gave me more information how to solve this issue.

1. Console output gave me information, that issue is located in `/root/.nbi/log/20231106131640.log`.
2. When I opened this file, issue was this: `Can't load library: /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/lib/libawt_xawt.so`
3. I have installed JDK once again: `sudo apt install openjdk-17-jdk`

Now, uninstall.sh (and also whole Netbeans software) can be run as expected.